# Access to soilgrid maps

Tags: r, soilgrids

I try to download TIFF layer from soilgrid in R version 4.3.2. I follow the example code that exists:

```
library(terra)
library(gdalUtilities)
bb=c(-337500.000,1242500.000,152500.000,527500.000) # Example bounding box (homolosine) for Ghana
igh='+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' # proj string for Homolosine projection

sg_url="/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/"
gdal_translate(
  paste0(sg_url,'ocs/ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt'),
  "./crop_roi_igh_r.tif",
  tr=c(250,250),
  projwin=bb,
  projwin_srs =igh
)
```

but I receive this error:

```
Warning message:
In CPL_gdaltranslate(source, destination, options, oo, config_options,  :
  GDAL Error 3: Cannot read 5920050 bytes
```

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Hate to say it but "works for me". Is it consistently failing with that exact same error for you? I get a 1960x2860 GeoTIFF which is 11221524 bytes big.

Comment: thank you.
yes the error for different bbox or layer is the same.

Comment: I've tried your code on two different computers now and it works on both. Version 1.2.4 of gdalUtilities with R 4.3.0 and `library(sf)` reports GDAL 3.0.4. Anyone else out there tried this?

Comment: thank you very much. is it possible the issue refers to internet connection problems?

Comment: Possibly, you could test this in R by doing `download.file("https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/ocs/ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt","test.vrt")` which tries to download the `vrt` file which is the same length as the error you are getting. Note this doesn't contain the actual data but is a virtual raster that has a list of tiles. It looks like your R isn't getting past the first stage of getting this `vrt` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the {terra} package which added a window() function efficiently reading a portion of a raster using a bounding box

```r
library(terra)

voi = "ocs" #define variable of interest
depth = "0-30cm"
quantile = "mean"

output_filename = "output.tif"

#in_crs="EPSG:4326" # CRS of the bounding box. use EPSG code or WKT 
#in this case the in_crs is not needed as it is already Interrupted Goode Homolosine (igh)

xmin = -337500.000 #bounding box xmin
xmax = 152500.000 #bounding box xmax
ymin = 527500.000 #bounding box ymin
ymax = 1242500.000 #bounding box ymax

bb=ext(c(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax))

igh = "ESRI:54052"

bb_igh = bb

# bb_igh= project(bb,from=crs(in_crs),to=crs(igh)) #only necessary where crs of bounding box is not igh

voi_layer = paste(voi,depth,quantile, sep="_") # layer of interest

rstFile = paste0("/vsicurl/https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/", voi, '/', voi_layer,'.vrt')


rst = rast(rstFile) # voi for whole world
crs(rst) = crs(igh)

window(rst) <- NULL
window(rst) = bb_igh # get just roi
plot(rst) #quick visual check

writeRaster(rst, output_filename, overwrite = TRUE)
```